# Comparing strings from files

Tags: c, string, file, stdio

I'm having a bit of problem. I want the program to search the file and if it matches with the input of the user, then the program will show "hello" and if not, it will show "bye". These outputs are just for testing purposes. Back to the problem. When it reaches the line of comparing, the program crashes. Now I'm clueless on how to solve the problem. I'm asking someone to help me please and thanks in advance. Below is a snippet of the code:

```
int CaseFunc();
int CaseFunc(){ 
FILE *memFile;
char memberfname[28];
char memberlname[28];
char ffname[28];
char flname[28];
char code;
struct PersonalInfo array[1000];
int memberage;
int menuANS;
int members;
int i;
members = 0;

printf("Enter your answer here: ");
scanf(" %d", &menuANS);

switch (menuANS){
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        printf("Enter code: ");
        scanf(" %c", &code);
        do {
            printf("Enter First Name: ");
            scanf("%s", memberfname);
            printf("Enter Last Name: ");
            scanf("%s", memberlname);
            printf("Enter Age: ");
            scanf("%d", &memberage);

            if ((memFile = fopen("TheCarDepot Members.txt", "a+")) == NULL){    //If the file path is incorrect, an error message is displayed
                fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening file  (%d: %s)\n",errno, strerror(errno)); //Error message that will be displayed if file path is incorrect
            return;
        }

        fprintf (memFile, "%s %s %d", memberfname,  memberlname,    memberage); 
        fprintf (memFile, "\n");            
        fclose(memFile);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf ("*%s %s is now a member of TheCarDepot Team.*\n", memberfname, memberlname);

        printf("Enter code: ");
        scanf(" %c", &code);
    }
    while (code != 'x');
    break;

    case 2:
        if ((memFile = fopen("TheCarDepot Members.txt", "r")) == NULL){ //If the file path is incorrect, an error message is displayed
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening file  (%d: %s)\n",errno, strerror(errno)); //Error message that will be displayed if file path is incorrect
            return;
        }

        //while the file is opened and not at the end, the strings are stored into variables which forms an array of strings
        for (members = 0; members < 200; members++) {
           if (fscanf(memFile, "%s %s %d", memberfname, memberlname, &memberage) == 3)  //Reads the contents of the file
               break;
           array[members].fname = strdup(memberfname);
           array[members].lname = strdup(memberlname);
           array[members].age = memberage;
        }
        fclose(memFile);

        printf("Enter your first name: ");
        scanf("%s", ffname);
        printf("\n");

        if (strcmp(array[members].fname, ffname) == 0){
            printf ("hello");
        }
        else if (strcmp(array[members].fname, ffname) != 0){
            printf ("bye");
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Which "line of comparing"? I see multiple if statements comparing things.

Comment: @CareyGregory the line where strcmp is used

Answer (score 0):

You must verify your `array[members].fname`, if it is a NULL, or it doesn't contain an end of string character, than it can crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (members = 0; members < 200; members++) {
           if (fscanf(memFile, "%s %s %d", memberfname, memberlname, &memberage) == 3)  //Reads the contents of the file
           break; //exit the loop if the reading is successful, the following lines are never executed
           array[members].fname = strdup(memberfname);
           array[members].lname = strdup(memberlname);
           array[members].age = memberage;
}
```

Basically you're manually exitting the loop, and never entering the values into the struct so the pointers are invalid.

Also you have a memory leak, `fname` and `lname` should be freed.

Comment: what do you mean by freed

Comment: @Kkkkkkkkkkkk something like `free(array[i].fname); free(array[i].lname);`

Comment: where should I put that? after storing it into the variables?

Comment: @Kkkkkkkkkkkk whenever you no longer need those variables, or you could change the struct's definition to use `char` arrays instead of pointers and use `strcpy` instead of `strdup`

Answer (score 0):

When you exit the `for` loop, `members` may be equal to 200, which is an uninitialized array entry. Passing it to `strcmp` could easily cause a crash.

Also, if you exit the loop early because `fscanf` succeeded, your `array` entry is also unitialized. Once again, this will likely cause a crash.

You need to initialize the `array` entry before exiting the loop, and you need to check to make sure `members` is < 200 before accessing that array entry.